# Heap Error while running spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata

I was Trying to run spark on my Ubuntu terminal but i am getting the following error

```
$Using /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle as default JAVA_HOME.
$Note, this will be overridden by -java-home if it is set.
$Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx10M -Xms2048M
$Error occurred during initialization of VM
$Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
```

Please Help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here](http://blog.paulgu.com/java/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap-size/) is a very cool Article that explains 6 Common Errors in Setting Java Heap Size hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

`-Xmx10M -Xms2048M`

The first argument is the maximum heap size and the second is the start that you are setting.  Max should be bigger than start.

Answer (score 0):

The `-Xms` and `-Xmx` parameters define the minimum and maximum heap sizes, respectively. You have set small value for `-Xmx` and large value for `-Xms` which is INVALID combination.

Have a look at this [vmoptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)  article by oracle for for better understanding.

Comment: Link is missing.

Comment: Updated the link now.